# How can I get a more realistic looking Tomato?

Tags: materials, shaders

I just modelled this tomato in blender 2.80 :

[image: Tomato_model]

and was wondering how could I get it to look more life like, after fiddling around with nodes I got this:

[image: Rendered_tomato[2]]

I used this node setup:

[image: node_setup]

How can I make it more realistic like this:

[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjt6Nb767bhAhUFf30KHW9lDrkQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwholesomebabyfood.momtastic.com%252Ftomatoesbabyfoodrecipes.htm%26psig%3DAOvVaw1W6Tz9U6tt-DvLA13iC_te%26ust%3D1554481216880514&psig=AOvVaw1W6Tz9U6tt-DvLA13iC_te&ust=1554481216880514]

I used 500 samples to render the image at 1080X1080.

Comment: actually your material is rather good, maybe give it a bit more glossiness, but I'd say your tail is not realistic though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in my opinion you can try featuring an environment or situation (e.g. some water drops on it? any mud on it? or creating a chopping block and knives?) or make some impefections (any wrinkles? or scratches?)

it's better to buy yourself a tomato and have a good look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the photo you provided is not realistic since it was heavily editied to look more "juicy". You can achive the same result by doing some postprocessing effect over the rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a brighter light, and maybe some leaves...or whatever those are...on the stem. Maybe add some gamma in post-processing.